# Class Not Found on Bitnami WordPress PHP 8

Tags: php, wordpress, bitnami

I am currently in the process of migrating an existing website to Amazon Lightsail which uses the Bitnami version of WordPress. WordPress is set up using symlinks and I'm wondering if that's what is causing the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "CSFramework_Abstract" not found in /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/roof/inc/theme-options/theme-extend/classes/framework.class.php:16
```

When tracing through the code, I am indeed returning the file paths to this file, except that it's returning at */opt/bitnami/wordress* vs */bitnami/wordpress*...

There are frequently errors with file permissions when setting up these servers, so I've ensured that I have my user and group set to bitnami:daemon with the proper file/directory permissions via chmod. That part should all be correct.

Is it possible for the class not found error to occur when either a path is incorrect or the permissions are incorrect?

My code hasn't changed at all. I though perhaps since I upgraded the version of PHP to 8+ that it was causing the issue, but the site runs fine locally on PHP 8.  I'm completely lost as to why I can't get this particular site to run using the Bitnami version of WordPress.

Comment: To answer your two questions in the second last paragraph: Yes. Is there anything else you'd like to know?

Comment: No thanks, I think I will remove the symlinks and put them in the main install folder to alleviate the issue.

Comment: Composer autoloader and PHP support symbolic links (if they are not dangling [=broken] naturally). You will notice that PHP itself most often resolves to the real pathname of every file it loads. If you see a difference between using symbolic links and not using symbolic links feel free to follow up. Also if removing the symbolic links does not resolve. From the error message alone this looks more to me that some autoloading is not properly initialized. Check the installation / initialization procedures for the components you're using specifically for autoloading as welll if still erroring.

Comment: Removing the symlinks resolved this issue :)